# How can I assign a lists elements to corresponding rows of a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have numbers in a List that should get assigned to certain rows of a dataframe consecutively.

****List=[2,5,7,12….]****

In my dataframe that looks similar to the below table, I need to do the following:

A frame_index that starts with **1** gets the next element of List as “sequence_number”

[image]

****Frame_Index==1** then** assign first element of List as Sequence_number.
Frame_index == 1 again, so assign second element of List as Sequence_number.
So my goal is to achieve a new dataframe like this:

[image]

I don't know which functions to use. If this weren't python language, I would use a for loop and check where frame_index==1, but my dataset is large and I need a pythonic way to achieve the described solution. I appreciate any help.

EDIT: I tried the following to fill with my List values to use fillna with ffill afterwards:

```py
     concatenated_df['Sequence_number']=[List[i] for i in 
     concatenated_df.index if (concatenated_df['Frame_Index'] == 1).any()]
```

But of course I'm getting "list index out of range" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do that in two steps.

1. Add column and fill with your list where frame_index == 1.
2. Use [df.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) with `method="ffill"` kwarg.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"frame_index": [1,2,3,4,1,2]})
sequence = [2,5]
df.loc[df["frame_index"] == 1, "sequence_number"] = sequence
df.ffill(inplace=True)  # alias for df.fillna(method="ffill")
```

This puts the `sequence_number` as `float64`, which might be acceptable in your use case, if you want it to be `int64`, then you can just force it when creating the column (line 4) or cast it later.

Comment: I have different length of rows. How to fill rows from 1 to 4 with 2's and then for the next one with 5's? As said I have different length of rows. I don't think that is can be done in your way.

Comment: I’ll edit in a while if you still haven’t found, but ffill (forward fill) does exactly what you said you’re looking for. Fill NA values using the last valid value, up to the next one. 

So it would fill rows 1 to 4 with the value in row 1, then use the value in row 5 until the end or the next valid value.

Comment: It would be great if you edit